# Splunk search a pattern

Tags: splunk

I want to search below pattern and result should show ONLY the line which matches the given pattern and that line must be UNIQUE -

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking into _raw coloumn than please try using regex in raw field.

Answer (score 2):

Below is one way to write your search query to get what you want.

```
... "Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:" | uniq
```

You can get more information at [Splunk's Search Command Reference](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/SearchCheatsheet)